# CakePHP paginator limit box

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Right now im using pagination to control my pages however i would like to add a `combobox` where there is a option where the user can set how many results he / she wants to see per site.

```
Paginator
```

Has a lot of options build in such as `paging` `counting` and so on so i was wondering if anyone knows if there is a buildin method for this aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this on-the-fly in your controller method:

```
 $this->paginate = array('limit'=>10);
```

Directly before your paginate call. So, you could pass this on as a named parameter such as limit:10 and then do:

```
$this->paginate = array('limit'=>$this->params['named']['limit']);
```

Here is a fuller example that assumes you are posting a form.

In your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create();?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('limit', array('options'=>array(10=>10, 20=>20, 30=>30)));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Show');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end()?>
```

In your controller method:

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['limit'])) {
   $this->paginate = array('limit'=>$this->request->data['limit']);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the thing is i don't want to do it on the fly i want the user to be able to choose and was wondering if paginator had a build in way of creating the selector

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You would need to do some variant of my example. If you look at my example, you can very easily work that into a means of allowing a user to select x per page from a select box.